# How Do I Have A Function Return more than true or false?

Tags: lua

-- For Example; I have this>

```
function test()
  input = io.read()
  if input == "1" then
    return -- value one
  elseif input == "2" then
    return -- value two
  elseif input == "3" then
    return -- value three
  end
end
```

-- Please note that the values must be able to be called separately :D

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function test()
  input = io.read()
  if input == "1" then
    return 1 -- value one
  elseif input == "2" then
    return 2 -- value two
  elseif input == "3" then
    return 3 -- value three
  end
end
```

Comment: Well I tried something like that and it ran in like.. a sort of line meaning: It would return value one no matter what was input, then it would return value 2 no matter the input, and then again for value 3, but if i wanted it to do something for value three without having to go through values 1 and 2, how might i do that?

Comment: @Eyres-Valkrie--CodeNoob- Lua can return any values, group of values, and the values can be any type like numbers, tables, functions.  Shivan answer does what you want. I recommend you go back to what you tried first and edit your question to show the error you were getting with "a sort of line": show code, show error, and line number.

Answer (score 0):

lol its late..

```
function test()
  return tonumber(io.read())
end
```